# Trying to load cities based on state value using select options tag and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I was using the information from this site http://jsfiddle.net/Q6h5s/ to create a drop down menu of Cities and States. When the State is selected the Cities belonging to that state should be selected. However all cities are being loaded. I am not too familiar with Javascript so I can't figure out where I am making this mistake.

Here is my code

```
<script>

    $("#state").change( function(){
        if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
            $(this).data('options',$('#city-name option').clone());
        }
        var id = $(this).val();
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[state=' + id + ']');
        $('#city-name').html(options);
    });
</script>

State:
<select id="state">
<?php
    $fs = new fsCreator();
    $cityState = $fs->loadCityState();
    $dbh = new DatabaseHandler();

    echo '<option value="0">State</option>';
    $temp = null;
    $sep = ',';
    $index = 0;
    $max = sizeof($cityState);
    for($i = 0; $i< $max; $i++){
        if(!($temp == substr($cityState[$i], 0, strpos($cityState[$i], $sep)))){
            $index++;
            $temp = substr($cityState[$i], 0, (strpos($cityState[$i], $sep)));
            echo '<option value="'.($index).'">'.(substr($cityState[$i], 0, strpos($cityState[$i], $sep))).'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
City:
<select id="city-name">
<?php
    $index = 0;
    $cityIndex = 0;
    $temp = null;
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
        if(!($temp == substr($cityState[$i], 0, strpos($cityState[$i], $sep)))){
            $index++;
            $temp = substr($cityState[$i], 0, strpos($cityState[$i], $sep));
        }
        $cityIndex++;
        echo '<option state="'.($index).'value="'.($cityIndex).'">'.(substr($cityState[$i], (strpos($cityState[$i], $sep)) + 1)).'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `state` attribute isn't set properly, which is what you're using to filter by.
you're missing a `"` at the end of it.

```
echo '<option state="'.($index).'" value="'.($cityIndex).'">'.(substr($cityState[$i], (strpos($cityState[$i], $sep)) + 1)).'</option>';
                                 ^^
```

Also you are attempting to bind an event handler to an object before it is created.
There are different ways to solve this

- Event delegation, bind the handler to the document

  ```
  $(document).on("change","#state", function(){
      if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
          $(this).data('options',$('#city-name option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[state=' + id + ']');
      $('#city-name').html(options);
  });
  ```
- Using the document load event

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#state").change( function(){
          if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
              $(this).data('options',$('#city-name option').clone());
          }
          var id = $(this).val();
          var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[state=' + id + ']');
          $('#city-name').html(options);
      });
  });
  ```
- Putting the code after the element in the markup

  ```
  State:
  <select id="state">
  ...
  </select>
  <script>

      $("#state").change( function(){
          if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
              $(this).data('options',$('#city-name option').clone());
          }
          var id = $(this).val();
          var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[state=' + id + ']');
          $('#city-name').html(options);
      });
  </script>
  ```

Comment: I can't have "state" and a separate "value" attribute??

Comment: can you explain a little more in detail?

Comment: You can have both attributes

Comment: Thank you very much. It did not fix the issue, however none the less you did point out a big mistake of mine.